# Derivation of general multistep method

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

I am having trouble understanding this derivation...

> Let us suppose that $\textbf{y}_n$ is the numerical solution at $t_n = t_0 + nh$, where $h >0$ is the step size. Now we attempt to find an algorithm that uses past values. Let's assume that
>   $$\textbf{y}_m = \textbf{y}(t_m) + O(h^{s+1}) \qquad m = 0,1,...,n+s-1$$
>   where $s\geq1$ is a given integer. Note that
>   $$\textbf{y}(t_{n+s}) = \textbf{y}(t_{n+s-1}) + \int_{t_{n+s-1}}^{t_{n+s}}\textbf{f}(\tau,\textbf{y}(\tau)) d\tau$$
>   and let 
>   $$\textbf{p}(t)= \sum_{m=0}^{s-1}p_m(t)\textbf{f}(t_{n+m},\textbf{y}_{n+m})$$where $p_m$ are the "shifted" Lagrange polynomials
>   $$p_m(t) = \prod_{l=0,l\neq m}^{s-1}\frac{t-t_{n+l}}{t_{n+m}-t_{n+l}}$$. We must have 
>   $$\textbf{p}(t_m)= \textbf{y}'(t_m)+ O(h^s) \qquad m= n,...,n+s-1 $$

I can understand this so far, but then

> using interpolation theory we can argue that
>   $$\textbf{p}(t)= \textbf{y}'(t)+ O(h^s) \qquad t \in [t_{n+s-1},t_{n+s}] (*)$$

It points to a theorem in the appendix that is given on page 6 of this document 
http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat772/fall10/lecture5
that is referred to as interpolation error.

I am having trouble understanding this because $[t_{n+s-1},t_{n+s}] $ falls outside the range of consideration! I do not see how you can deduce that given  we have a Lagrange interpolating polynomial that agrees with nodes 
$$t_n,t_{n+1},...,t_{n+s-1}$$

> How does the linked theorem help us conclude $(*)$ from above?

Comment: You're right that this is saying that the derivative is nicely approximated in a region that you didn't actually use to obtain the polynomial interpolant. Thus the result is basically saying that a polynomial interpolant of a nice function is accurate even a little bit outside of the region of interpolation. For intuition, consider drawing a secant line for $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=0$ and $x=h$. Presumably the value of the secant line at $x=2h$ should be only an $O(h^2)$ deviation from $f(2h)=4h^2$, and indeed it is $2h^2$.

Comment: When first reading this part of the book I thought exactly this! But the way it was stated made me think that there was some clear deduction we could make from said theorem to prove that "our intuition" is the case.

Comment: There is, but it requires you to grind out the machinery of interpolation theory. I don't know a way to dodge that. Also, my last example was bad because of the small derivative in the relevant range. You should instead consider $f(x)=x^2,x=1,x=1+h$, so that $f(1+2h)=1+4h+4h^2,g(1+2h)=1+(2h+h^2)(2h)=1+4h+2h^2$, so they agree up to $O(h^2)$.

Comment: Could you perhaps give me a hint? I seems like a fascinating result. Perhaps a source?

Comment: I forget whether Tim Sauer's *Numerical Analysis* goes through this, but that is my "go to" for this sort of thing, at least for a first check. I have to look in harder-to-read references to find the stuff that isn't there.